# How to change the time to the format with moment and datePicker AntD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

How to change the time to the format when the day is 23 o'clock. For example, when I click on 23 in the datapicker, 11 is shown, but i want to see 23

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-euclid-9bfce?file=/index.js)

```
function onChange(date, dateString) {
  console.log(date, dateString);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Space direction="vertical">
    <DatePicker
      allowClear
      placeholder="укажите дату"
      local="ISO 8601"
      showTime={{
        defaultValue: moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")
      }}
      format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </Space>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowercase, i.e. 'h' or 'hh' is used for 12 hour format in momentjs. 
Now since you want a 24 hour format, use 'H' or 'HH'. Use `format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`. This should work.